# nvme RxErr and pcieport Timeout error in linux logs

Tags: linux, fedora, logs

I am new to Linux and have just successfully installed
Fedora 32 on my laptop. I have noticed I get the following errors inside Logs. Could you please guide me on how to go about solving these errors?

```
Hardware nvme 0000:04:00.0: AER: [0] RxERR 117
Hardware pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: [12] Timeout
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. If possible, please don't post [screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), but copy-and-paste it into your question with proper formatting; otherwiese it won't show up for others having the same problem who google for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding `pci=noaer` to your kernel command line:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and and add `pci=noaer` to the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. It will look like this:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rhgb quiet pci=noaer"`

Then you could run `grub2-mkconfig` or `grubby` to apply these changes: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/

A similar bug is being tracked here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173

It would be great if you filed a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/

Comment: Thank you. This worked!

Comment: @FernandoSwenson If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.